# Using Vite React with C++ Emscripten + Multithreaded Web Workers

Tags: vite, webassembly, web-worker, emscripten, rollupjs

I'm trying to setup a project using Vite React + C++ code compiled with Emscripten with multithreading via web workers enabled. This works fine with a development build using `npm run dev` but fails during compilation with `npm run build`.

The error message I get is:

```
Error: Unexpected early exit. This happens when Promises returned by plugins cannot resolve. Unfinished hook action(s) on exit:
(vite:worker-import-meta-url) transform "path/to/src/utils/penguin_app.js"
    at process.handleBeforeExit (file:///path/to/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25670:28)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at process.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this problem or has gotten Vite + Multithreaded Emscripten working? I suspect this has something to do with the way Vite imports web workers and it not being compatible with the Emscripten generated web worker file but I haven't been able to narrow down the problem yet. Removing the -pthread flag so only a `.js` and `.wasm` file are generated works fine with build.

I compiled the C++ code with this: `emcc -lembind -pthread -s MODULARIZE=1 -s EXPORT_ES6=1 --no-entry -o penguin_app.js libs/cat/cats.cpp libs/penguin/penguins.cpp`

I've also setup a Minimum Reproducible Example [here](https://github.com/verySmolBrain/wasm_help) that includes the source code for `penguins.cpp` and `cats.cpp` as well as my `vite.config.ts` and `tsconfig.json`

I've tried manually editing the `.js` file. The suspected lines are:

```
worker = new Worker(new URL('./penguin_app.worker.js', import.meta.url));
```

in `penguin_app.js` and

```
      (e.data.urlOrBlob ? import(e.data.urlOrBlob) : import('./penguin_app.js'))
      .then(exports => exports.default(Module));
```

in `penguin_app.worker.js`. Removing either of these lines means the build completes but since I've removed the imports the WASM file never actually gets loaded. I'm not sure what the issue is with these snippets since from what I've read, they seem fine.

The closest thing I've found related to my issue is this [github issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/13367) but I'm not sure how this is applicable. I've also looked into getting it working with WebPack and while I've found a solution for that, I'm more interested in how to set this up for Vite.

I've also tried using `optimizeDeps` in `vite.config.ts` by both including and excluding the `.js` file and `.worker.js` file but that doesn't seem to affect anything.

I've also played around with ES6 vs CommonJS differences by changing the file extensions for `.worker.js` to `.worker.cjs` and `.js` to `.mjs` but that doesn't change anything either. This might have something to do with Emscripten's ES6 export option but I've found having Emscripten export as CommonJS makes things very fiddly when trying to integrate it with Vite React.

Any advice or rabbitholes to go down would be greatly appreciated since I'm completely stuck right now.

Comment: Emscripten outputs workers that then import the script that created them to gain access to some resources. [This creates a circular dependency](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/14329) that Vite has trouble analyzing: the lib.js file "imports" the lib.worker.js file via the Worker constructor, and the lib.worker.js then imports the lib.js file in turn. The closest thing I've seen to a fix is [this, to keep Vite from analyzing the worker at all at build time.](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7015#issuecomment-1304771043)